# Emacs jabber set status for gmail talk

Tags: emacs, xmpp

Is it possible to change the status on Gmail's talk when connecting through jabber.el?

In my browser I've set "busy", but in jabber it still says "online". I'd like to be able to set to "invisible" too, if that is possible.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following key bindings:

- <kbd>C-x C-j C-a</kbd> - away
- <kbd>C-x C-j C-x</kbd> - extended away
- <kbd>C-x C-j C-o</kbd> - online

There are two other options ("do not disturb" and "available for chat").  You can access these, as well as the option to enter a custom message, using <kbd>C-x C-j C-p</kbd> (for `jabber-send-presence`).

Being "invisible" is not supported directly, but if you turn on the console (set `jabber-debug-log-xml` to `t` and switch to the `*-jabber-console-JID-*` buffer), you should be able to follow the instructions at http://chinmaykamat.wordpress.com/2010/01/22/google-talk-invisible-mode-in-pidgin/.

Comment: Thank you for the invisibility trick, will try it. The keybindings I saw in the manual but didn't work - the problem was on my side.